# Custom grid in foundation?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I need a different sized grid within the standard grid layout.

I'm using sass and have tried:

```
.row-30{
    @include grid-row($total-columns: 30);
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row-30">
    <div class="small-5 columns">a 5 col</div>
    <div class="small-1 columns end">a 1 col</div>
</div>
```

I'm having no luck though. Where am I going wrong with this mixin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you also need to bring in the `grid-html-classes` for the size you want..

```
$total-columns: 30;

.row-30 {
    @include grid-row($total-columns);
    @include grid-html-classes($size:small);
}
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/QIvdO5M7Tz

Comment: It looks like you don't even have to include $total-columns inside the grid-row function. I'm guessing if you were using this in production though you would want to reset $total-columns back to the desired amount?